# iOS 11 UiTableViewCell Location issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios11, ios10.3

I have a four UITableView cell one after another. On iOS 10.3 the first cell is right after the status bar but in iOS 11 there is some space between the status bar and the first cell.

[image: Attached the image of both screenshots from iOS 10.3 and iOS 11]

Comment: is there an iOS 11 stable version? 
On my opinion, such questions should be for stable iOS. Because it is still in beta and some thing could change before release.

Comment: This is an issue till iOS 11 beta 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be due to newly introduced [`contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior)

By default is set to `.automatic` but it can be disabled switching it to `.never`:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never
}
```

Comment: did change anything for me. Anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue in iOS 11. The empty spaces was header and footer. In iOS < 11 it was enough to set `heightForHeaderInSection` and `heightForFooterInSection` to `CGFLOAT_MIN`. In iOS 11 I had also to return nil in `viewForHeaderInSection` and `viewForFooterInSection`.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:    (NSInteger)section {
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nil;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nil;
}
```